# how to post nested Json Array to server?

Tags: android, json, post

Hi i want to post this a json array which has two json arrays of Integers in them to server using JsonObject

```
"job_experiences": [
        {
            "job_category": [Integer],
            "experience_level": [Integer]
        }
    ]


  JsonArray list = new JsonArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedJobs.size(); i++) {
                list.add(selectedJobs.get(i));
            }
            JsonArray list2 = new JsonArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedJobs.size(); i++) {
                list2.add(selectedJobs.get(i));
            }




            JsonObject postData = new JsonObject();

        postData.add("job_category", list);
        postData.add("experience_level", list2);
```

Comment: what problem or on which line you are facing the error or issue ?

Comment: not getting posted to the server, just want to know proper format to post it

Comment: please check my below answer.

Comment: have you get solution from my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `JSONObject` instead of `JsonObject` and `JSONArray` instead of `JsonArray`,
Try below approach and check

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < selectedJobs.size(); i++) {
  list.put(selectedJobs.get(i));
}

JSONArray list2 = new JSONArray();

for (int i = 0; i < selectedJobs.size(); i++) {
  list2.put(selectedJobs.get(i));
}


JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();


try {
      postData.put("job_category", list);
      postData.put("experience_level", list2);

      JSONArray job_experiences = new JSONArray();
      job_experiences.put(postData);

      JSONObject jsonObject_job_experiences = new JSONObject();
      jsonObject_job_experiences.put("job_experiences", job_experiences);

      Log.e("jsonObject_job_exp", jsonObject_job_experiences.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and in the log you can see the final `JSONObject`

Comment: but what about job_experiences" [] ?

Comment: @ANDROID_ROOKIE, i have updated  my answer, please check

Comment: @ANDROID_ROOKIE, i have recent more update my answer, you can see the log value  **Log.e("jsonObject_job_exp", jsonObject_job_experiences.toString());** which is mention in my answer as final JSONObjest you want.